# Installing crontab file on Solaris?

Tags: solaris

Typically we use crontab -u   in our recipes. However we have a few Solaris 10 boxen where the flavor of crontab won't support the -u flag. Is there a way to deploy an existing crontab file using Solaris' crontab command? How?

Answer (score 2):

This should be equivalent to `crontab -u user filename` :

```
su user -c "'crontab filename'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this trick before to solve the Solaris problem:

```
EDITOR="cat $file >" VISUAL="cat $file >" crontab -e "$user"
```